# Python module: OpenCV open source

Tags: python, opencv, module

I have modules OpenCV was added.
But I can't import it.

```
import cv2 #name 'cv2' is not defined
```

Sorry for this simple question. I'm newbie and I can't find the answer

My modules when I checked by help("modules")

[image]

Comment: I posted an image in the blue line ^^

Comment: You installed `cv2` in Python 3.6. Are you certain that the error also happens in Python 3.6?

Comment: Yes. I can't find out what happen

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43299096/python-cannot-see-installed-module-news for things to try in your debugging.

Comment: Thanks. I founded how to fix it. I change my version down to 2.7.5 and use numpy 32bit to add new module and it work! But when I open in Visual Studio 2017 environment, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe your package it's not installed correctly try this :

```
pip uninstall cv2
pip uninstall cv2
```

in your command line

Comment: Thanks. Now I can solve this problem ^^ Thanks alot <3